# Three js coordinate system; what are the units expressed as?

Tags: canvas, three.js

I am just starting out with Three.js, and I have trouble understanding the coordinate system used.

The Getting Started Manual includes a [Drawing Lines](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Drawing-lines) section. Amongst others it includes the following:

```
const points = [];
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );
```

These points are then converted to a geometry object, which is then used to create a line, which is in turn added to the scene.

Running the code from the manual work and there's indeed a line on the screen. Great! I understand the code itself, only I do not understand what the x,y,z values in the `Vector3` are? As in, what unit are they in?

I understand that the center of the canvas object, on which the scene is displayed is (0,0,0). However, then in what units are the points created above expressed? It appears to completely arbitrary to me.

I tried to figure it out with the following: I created a canvas with a size of (1000, 1000) pixels:

```
renderer.setSize(
        1000, 
        1000
    )
```

Initially, I expected that a line drawn from (-1000,0) to (1000,0) or perhaps (-500,0) to (500,0) would go from the left of the canvas to the right. However, instead, it seems that the left and right x values are actually somewhere around -86 to 86, which seems entirely arbitrary to me.

I realized that the camera position has an influence, too. The tutorial used a perspective camera, which I set to the following, with the intention of figuring out the units

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);  
camera.position.set(0,0,100)
```

Changing the first input, the pov, or the z location of the camera position, changes the size of the lines. However, I do not understand the relation between the values and what I see on the screen.

I have tried a lot of combinations of the canvas size, the camera position and PoV, to somehow come to the value of x that corresponds to the edges of my canvas, but I have not managed to find a correct formula.

If I wanted to draw a line exactly from the left edge of my canvas to the right edge to my canvas, how would I do this? And from top to bottom?

I have tried to read more about the coordinate system but I have not figured it out.

Comment: Use `THREE.OrthographicCamera`, as an option. About units in three.js: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/units-in-three-js/1174/5